# Advice on fine-tuning query and index for performance

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, index-tuning, query-performance

Currently my query is as below:

```
select id_request,username_request
  from darkhast_follower
 where darkhast_follower.id_request != '9762952594' 
   AND darkhast_follower.status =0 
   AND NOT exists ( select null
               from log_follow 
               where log_follow.other_id = darkhast_follower.id_request 
               AND log_follow.id= '9762952594' LIMIT 1)
 LIMIT 1
```

Table `log_follow` has 30 milion rows and `darkhast_follower` has 1000 rows respectively.

`log_follow` is indexed on column `(other_id)` and `(id)`, `darkhast_follower` is indexed on column `(id_request)` and `(status)`.

The performance seems to be slow and looking for expert advice on fine-tuning the query and index suggestion. Currently I have 40k active users.

```
-- Server version: 5.7.23-log
-- PHP Version: 5.6.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `darkhast_follower`
--

CREATE TABLE `darkhast_follower` (
  `IDD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `id_request` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username_request` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `token_id` text NOT NULL,
  `darkhasti` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `daryafti` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `date` text NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gsm_sender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `error_report` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `bot` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `back` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- 
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `darkhast_follower`
--
ALTER TABLE `darkhast_follower`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`IDD`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`),
  ADD KEY `id_request` (`id_request`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables 
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `darkhast_follower`
--
ALTER TABLE `darkhast_follower`
  MODIFY `IDD` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;


SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

 -- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `log_follow`
--

CREATE TABLE `log_follow` (
  `IDD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `other_user` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `other_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `log_follow`
--
ALTER TABLE `log_follow`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`IDD`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`),
  ADD KEY `other_id` (`other_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `log_follow`
--
ALTER TABLE `log_follow`
  MODIFY `IDD` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

[image: darkhast_follower]
[image: log_follow]

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE! Could you post the DDL for these tables & indexes please? DDL is always better than images as it helps us recreate the issue you are having. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone What is DDL?

Comment: DDL stands for Data Definition Language. Essentially, the `CREATE TABLE` & `CREATE INDEX` statements.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone added

Comment: Please add the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for your query. And how much time it takes on average. *" performance seems to be slow"*: is it 10 ms slow or 10 min slow?

Comment: Do you intend for this is to be != (not equal)
where darkhast_follower.id_request != '9762952594'
which will CAUSE a TABLE SCAN.  
Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT ... for your query AND B) SHOW INDEX FROM darkhast_follower; AND C) SHOW INDEX FROM log_follow; D) SHOW CREATE TABLE darkhast_follower; E) SHOW CREATE TABLE log_follow;

Comment: @MarvanEimaz When you have time to post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT ... for you query, we will be able to analyze this query for you.  Unfortunately, the screen shots of tables and indexes do not name the table the information belongs to.  SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename; and SHOW INDEX FROM table_name does a better job of documenting.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The query seems ok (although the `LIMIT 1` inside the `NOT EXISTS` subquery is not needed) but you are probably missing some index. I suggest:

- add a composite index on `log_follow (id, other_id)`:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE log_follow
    ADD INDEX id_other_id_idx
      (id, other_id) ;
  ```
- an index on `darkhast_follower (status, id_request)` might help as well but with such a small table, probably not much.
- the datatype of the various id columns (`id`, `other_id`, `id_request`) are `varchar(20)` with charset `UTF8`. If you only have ASCII characters there, it would be better to use Latin charset. This will lower the column width from 60 (20x3) bytes to 20, and thus reduce the index size, both in disk and memory. If you only store integers in these columns, it would be even better to use `BIGINT`, reducing the size to 8 bytes.

Comment: latin charset like?
both column indexed log_follow (id, other_id)

Comment: I suggest a single composite index on both columns. You have 2 indexes, on each column separately.